# Jenkins pipeline for JFrog Artifactory fails to publish BuildInfo

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have `Jenkinsfile` written in `groovy` as follows:

```
env.MVN_Goals = MVN_Goals
node {
 // Get Artifactory server instance, defined in the Artifactory Plugin administration page.
def server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'http://localhost:8085/artifactory', username: 'admin', password: 'password'
 // Create an Artifactory Maven instance.
 def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()

 stage ('Clone sources'){
     git url: 'D:/Sample GIT_Maven Repo'
 }

 stage 'Artifactory configuration'
    rtMaven.deployer releaseRepo:'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo:'libs-snapshot-local', server: server
    rtMaven.resolver releaseRepo:'libs-release', snapshotRepo:'libs-snapshot', server: server
    def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()


 stage('Maven_Build'){

 if (isUnix()) {
    sh "D:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn -B -Dmaven ${MVN_Goals}"
 }

 else{
    bat "D:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin/mvn -B -Dmaven ${MVN_Goals}"
 }

 step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: '**/target/*.jar', fingerprint: true])
}
stage ('Publish build info'){
     server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
 }
}
```

I tried configuring the Artifactory in Jenkins by adding the Artifactory plugin for Jenkins. When I tried to test the connection, I am getting an error as `There is either an incompatible or no instance of Artifactory at the provided URL`. The same error is occurring when i tried to build my job in Jenkins. Is there a way to resolve it?

Artifactory plugin version - `2.9.1`

Artifactory Version - `4.15.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()` is within that particular stage.

Modify that as

```
env.MVN_Goals = MVN_Goals

node {

// Get Artifactory server instance,
// defined in the Artifactory Plugin administration page.

def server = Artifactory.newServer url: 'http://localhost:8085/artifactory', username: 'admin', password: 'password'

// Create an Artifactory Maven instance.

def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()

def buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()

stage ('Clone sources'){

    git url: 'D:/Sample GIT_Maven Repo'
}
```